# pyramid checkboxes

Tags: python, checkbox, pyramid

I'm just new to python and pyramid and I'm struggling with how to process the results of a form containing multiple checkboxes in Pyramid.

Here is an excerpt from my form:

```
<p tal:repeat="category categories">
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedcategories" value="${category.id}"> ${category.name}<br/>
</p>
```

And here is how I am currently trying to iterate through and process the results:

```
selectedcategories=request.params['selectedcategories']    
for categoryid in selectedcategories:
        category = DBSession.query(Category).filter_by(id=categoryid).one()
        article.categories.append(category)
```

As you may have guessed, I'm only getting a maximum of one checkbox recognized no matter how many I select on the form. Django has an option to return the results as a list, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that with Pyramid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`request.params` is a [multidict](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/webob.html#multidict-narr). To retrieve multiple values, you can call its [getall()](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/interfaces.html#pyramid.interfaces.IMultiDict.getall) method:

```
selectedcategories = request.params.getall("selectedcategories")
```